# Using grep in python

Tags: python, grep

There is a file (query.txt) which has some keywords/phrases which are to be matched with other files using grep. The last three lines of the following code are working perfectly but when the same command is used inside the while loop it goes into an infinite loop or something(ie doesn't respond).

```
import os

f=open('query.txt','r')
b=f.readline()
while b:
    cmd='grep %s my2.txt'%b    #my2 is the file in which we are looking for b
    os.system(cmd)
    b=f.readline()
f.close()

a='He is'
cmd='grep %s my2.txt'%a
os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: Why use `grep` when you've got the `re` module in Python?

Comment: This is an assignment. We are told you use grep :(

Comment: You need quotes in your constructed command line if your search pattern has a space in it, as it is in the last 3 lines of your test.  You want the command to read:
`grep "He is" my2.txt`
But as it stands here, the command line is:
`grep He is my2.txt`

Answer (score 10):

First of all, you are not iterating over the file properly. You can simply use `for b in f:` without the `.readline()` stuff.

Then your code will blow in your face as soon as the filename contains any characters which have a special meaning in the shell. Use [`subprocess.call`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) instead of `os.system()` and pass an argument list.

Here's a fixed version:

```
import os
import subprocess
with open('query.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip() # remove trailing whitespace such as '\n'
        subprocess.call(['/bin/grep', line, 'my2.txt'])
```

---

However, you can improve your code even more by not calling `grep` at all.
Read `my2.txt` to a string instead and then use the `re` module to perform the search. In case you do not need a regex at all, you can even simply use `if line in my2_content`

Comment: Hi, Thank You for your response. And I am required to use grep because this is an assignment. And after using your code I'm getting the following error
**grep: is: No such file or directory**

Comment: @user1171232: See my comment to eumiro's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Your code scans the whole `my2.txt` file for each query in `query.txt`.

You want to:

1. read all queries into a list
2. iterate once over all lines of the text file and check each file against all queries.

Try this code:

```
with open('query.txt','r') as f:
    queries = [l.strip() for l in f]

with open('my2.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for query in queries:
            if query in line:
                print query, line
```

Comment: Also, `readline()` keeps the line terminator `\n` in the returned string which probably confuses `grep` additionally.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't actually a good way to use Python, but if you have to do something like that, then do it correctly:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
import subprocess

def grep_lines(filename, query_filename):
    with open(query_filename, "rb") as myfile:
        for line in myfile:
             subprocess.call(["/bin/grep", line.strip(), filename])

grep_lines("my2.txt", "query.txt")
```

And hope that your file doesn't contain any characters which have special meanings in regular expressions =)

Also, you might be able to do this with `grep` alone:

```
grep -f query.txt my2.txt
```

It works like this:

```
~ $ cat my2.txt 
One two
two two
two three
~ $ cat query.txt 
two two
three
~ $ python bar.py 
two two
two three
```

Comment: Hi, Thank You for your response. And I am required to use grep in python because this is an assignment and we're told to do it this way.
And after using your code I'm getting the following error **grep: is: No such file or directory**

Comment: @user1171232: What's in your `query.txt`? Does `subprocess.call(["/bin/grep", "-e", line.strip(), filename])` work better?

Comment: Query.txt has keywords/phrases seperated by newline. ANd no the change does no good and is showing the same error.

Comment: @user1171232: I've added an example that shows the code works here. I'm not sure I can help you further without you telling me what's in your `query.txt`.

Comment: I wrote in the above comment what query.txt has. It has keywords seperated by newline. These are those keywords which are to be matched in my2.txt. Thanks

Comment: nikita@nikita-laptop:~/bin$ cat my2.txt
This document is about my dog. His name is whisky. He is 10months old.
nikita@nikita-laptop:~/bin$ cat query.txt
'name'
'My name is nikita'
'whisky'
nikita@nikita-laptop:~/bin$ python f.py
grep: is: No such file or directory
my2.txt:This document is about my dog. His name is whisky. He is 10months old.
nikita@nikita-laptop:~/bin$

Comment: I found the problem i think. The error was because of the last three lines as shown in my code. I removed them. But now this code is not printing any result. ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep -wFf query.txt my2.txt > out.txt
```

this will match all the keywords in query.txt with my2.txt file and save the output in out.txt

Read `man grep` for a description of all the possible arguments.