# How to use grep in IPython?

Tags: python, ipython, pythonxy

I have installed PythonXY. How do I use or install `grep` or a `grep` like function in IPython? It gives an error that `grep` is not defined. I want to search for text in text files in a directory.

Comment: See [using grep in python in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018109/using-grep-in-python)

Comment: which os you are working on?

Comment: Why use grep? Why not use Python's own regex functions? Load the file and search it.

Comment: I am on a windows system

Answer (score 3):

With just python (>=2.5) code:

```
import fileinput
import re
import glob

def grep(PAT, FILES):
    for line in fileinput.input(glob.glob(FILES)):
        if re.search(PAT, line):
            print fileinput.filename(), fileinput.lineno(), line
```

Then you can use it this way:

```
grep('text', 'path/to/files/*')
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are on a *nix system you can do:

File: *file_1.txt*

```
this is line one
this is line two
this is line three
```

Code:

```
import os
import subprocess

os.system('grep one file_1.txt')
subprocess.call(['grep', 'one', 'file_1.txt'])
```

Output in both cases:

```
this is line one
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its kind of late for answer here, but I just finished a simple project implementing just that!

##### installation

`pip install greps`

##### usage

```
%load_ext greps

In [1]: {i:i for i in range(3)}
Out[1]: 
{0: 0,
 1: 1,
 2: 2,
}
 
In [2]: %greps 1
Out[2]: ' 1: 1,\n'
```

you can find more information in the repo: https://github.com/royreznik/greps