# Fastest way to search for *any* number in string w/o Regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

I am a relatively new developer and I have an issue where I am trying to search a string for a specific pattern that *may* contain a number at a specific position in a single line of a text file.

the method that I am currently writing ingests a single line from that trace file and will need to look for a match against a dictionary of known patterns.

Now, I have heard from my friends who are *actual* developers of python programs that Regex is actually a relatively slow and inefficient way to perform this sort of operation. But given the nature of my issue i cant think of a way to do it without them.

The process that I am developing will run over nearly 10,000 text files with 200k+ lines each.

Can anyone think of a faster way to do this?

```
def firm_parser(line):
    RgxFrm_PX={
    "CycleCount":{
        "ptrn":re.search(re.compile(r"P\d{1}RV"),line),
        "desc":"Request cycle counter",
        "deet":""},
    "LastAdjustDate":{
        "ptrn":re.search(re.compile(r"P\d{1}RJ"),line),
        "desc":"Request adjustment date and status",
        "deet":""},
    "ChanTemp":{
        "prtn":re.search(re.compile(r"P\d{1}RM"),line),
        "desc":"Request pipetting channel temperature",
        "deet":""}
        }

    for key,value in RgxFrm_PX:
        if value["prtn"]:
            print(f"{value["desc"]} {line}")
```

Comment: https://thenewstack.io/tutorial-find-strings-in-text-files-using-grep-with-regular-expressions/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018109/using-grep-in-python

Comment: You should compile your pattern(s) outside of the loop. Otherwise I'd imagine there's no benefit to using `re.compile`. I would try that before requiring "no regex."

Comment: @jpf thank you so much for the info!  I really am curious why people downvoted this question? Am i breaking some rule or norm by asking this?

Comment: np. Not to my knowledge. Looks like it was reversed.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I gave it a try, not expecting a bog difference between the regex and the no-regex method, and dang was I surprised!

Here's my version of the function, without regex:

```py
def firm_parserV2(line):
    pattern_found = False

    matches = []

    lineCpy = line
    while 1:
        idx = lineCpy.find('P')
        if idx < 0: break

        lineCpy = lineCpy[idx+1:]
        if not lineCpy[0].isnumeric():
            continue

        matches.append([
            lineCpy[1:3],    # The 2 letters
            int(lineCpy[0])  # The number
        ])

    for letters, number in matches:
        if letters == 'RV':
            message = "Request cycle counter"
        elif letters == 'RJ':
            message = "Request adjustment date and status"
        elif letters == 'RM':
            message = "Request pipetting channel temperature"

        print(message, line)
```

I compared the times for a small line (`P4RJasd`), and here are the results:

```
+------------------------------+------------------------+
| Function                     | Time                   |
+------------------------------+------------------------+
| Original                     | .003547472953796386 ms |
+------------------------------+------------------------+
| Original with rx compilation | .002606389522552490 ms |
|  outside the function        |                        |
+------------------------------+------------------------+
| New version                  | .000612576007843017 ms |
+------------------------------+------------------------+
```

---

Here's the full code I used to compare the 3 functions:

```py
import re
import re
import time
import random

def firm_parser(line):
    RgxFrm_PX={
        "CycleCount":{
            "prtn":re.search(re.compile(r"P\d{1}RV"),line),
            "desc":"Request cycle counter",
            "deet":""},
        "LastAdjustDate":{
            "prtn":re.search(re.compile(r"P\d{1}RJ"),line),
            "desc":"Request adjustment date and status",
            "deet":""},
        "ChanTemp":{
            "prtn":re.search(re.compile(r"P\d{1}RM"),line),
            "desc":"Request pipetting channel temperature",
            "deet":""}
    }

    for key,value in RgxFrm_PX.items():
        if value["prtn"]:
            pass
            # print(f"{value['desc']} {line}")


rx_rv = re.compile(r"P\dRV")
rx_rj = re.compile(r"P\dRJ")
rx_rm = re.compile(r"P\dRM")

def firm_parser_no_rx(line):
    RgxFrm_PX={
        "CycleCount":{
            "prtn":re.search(rx_rv, line),
            "desc":"Request cycle counter",
            "deet":""},
        "LastAdjustDate":{
            "prtn":re.search(rx_rj, line),
            "desc":"Request adjustment date and status",
            "deet":""},
        "ChanTemp":{
            "prtn":re.search(rx_rm, line),
            "desc":"Request pipetting channel temperature",
            "deet":""}
    }

    for key,value in RgxFrm_PX.items():
        if value["prtn"]:
            pass
            # print(f"{value['desc']} {line}")

def firm_parserV2(line):
    pattern_found = False

    matches = []

    lineCpy = line
    while 1:
        idx = lineCpy.find('P')
        if idx < 0: break

        lineCpy = lineCpy[idx+1:]
        if not lineCpy[0].isnumeric():
            continue

        matches.append([
            lineCpy[1:3],    # The 2 letters
            int(lineCpy[0])  # The number
        ])

    for letters, number in matches:
        if letters == 'RV':
            message = "Request cycle counter"
        elif letters == 'RJ':
            message = "Request adjustment date and status"
        elif letters == 'RM':
            message = "Request pipetting channel temperature"

        # print(message, line)

loop_nb = 100000
test_string = 'P4RJasd'
funcs = [
    firm_parser,
    firm_parser_no_rx,
    firm_parserV2
]
times = {}

for func in funcs: times[func.__name__] = 0

for i in range(loop_nb):
    # Scrambling the array...
    funcs = sorted(funcs, key = lambda x: random.random() )

    for func in funcs:
        start = time.time()
        func(test_string)
        end = time.time()
        times[func.__name__] += (end - start)


for func, time in times.items():
    print(func + '\t', time / loop_nb)
```

Comment: I would try it with pre-compiled patterns, outside of the line loop, as mentioned in original post comments. Otherwise it's sort of cheating to force regex to compile the pattern every line (unless it happens to be stored in cache and remembered... somehow).

Comment: Arh, indeed, when you take the compilation out of the function, it's much faster! I'll update my answer

Comment: Also consider doing loops (say, 10000) over each approach, and do each approach in different orders, to get true time difference. Otherwise sometimes the machinery behind the scenes, having nothing  to do with the problem at hand, can bias results.

Comment: Also, shouldn't print anything during testing. The print function itself can corrupt comparison - different things are printed in each version, for example.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance! I updated my answer to add everything you mentioned

Comment: Well then... Im blown away to get such in depth responses. Thank you so much guys!